# mockStatic: mock java.lang with PowerMock

Tags: static, mockito, powermock, java

I am trying to mock `MBeanServer` with Mockito, but my attempts fails.

```
@Test
public void testGetAllCacheProperties() {
    mockStatic(ManagementFactory.class);
    MBeanServer server = MBeanServerFactory.newMBeanServer();
    ObjectInstance inst = server.registerMBean(new MyBeanService(), ObjectName.getInstance(SERVICE_NAME));  
    given(ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()).willReturn(server);
}
```

I suppose to inject my mock into method that normally runs on `jBoss AS 7`:

```
@GET
public Response getAllProperties() {
    MBeanServer platformMBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
```

But it fails with exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
JmxMBeanServer cannot be returned by getPlatformMBeanServer()
getPlatformMBeanServer() should return MBeanServer
```

---

**Update**

When I try

```
 PowerMockito.doReturn(server).when(ManagementFactory.class, "getPlatformMBeanServer");
```

I get exception:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;" the class loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) of the current class, my_package_for_test_class.TestClass, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for the method's defining class, java/lang/management/ManagementFactory, have different Class objects for the type javax/management/MBeanServer used in the signature
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not possible to mock static from `java.lang` package, since PowerMock tries to change bite code and bite code of `java.lang` classes
 obviously protected from modifications.

There is work around suggested by [Johan Haleby](https://www.jayway.com/2009/05/17/mocking-static-methods-in-java-system-classes/).
You have to create wrapper class:

```
public class JmxUtils {

    public static MBeanServer getPlatformMbeanServer() {
        return ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    }
}
```

Then test will look like this

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(JmxUtils.class)
public class CacheControllerTest {
    //.. preconditions
    given(JmxUtils.getPlatformMbeanServer()).willReturn(server);
```